# iphone css: media type not working!

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

I am working on a site specific to the iphone community. Having read few articles on the net, regarding css for the iphone safari browser I learnt to use the following code:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iPhone.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

However when I use it on the html pages it's not working. Basically it's not even applying the css file to the content.

Example Links:
Without the media type: http://www.indiatourismhelpline.com/ip/page-1.html
With the media type: http://www.indiatourismhelpline.com/ip/page-2.html

Hope the viewing the source of the files would help you to understand the issue. There must be something I am doing wrong here, have been trying for hours but just can't get it to work.

Please help!

Comment: I can see both links correct on iphone, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's okay..it was a caching issue. Solved it :-)
Thanks for your comment... appreciate it.